# VS Code: Pylance не видит установленные библиотеки

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

При попытке импортировать `PyGithub` или перейти к исходному коду библиотеки `Pylance` ничего не предлагает и не делает.

Если переустановить `Pylance`, то проблема решится, но появится снова после перезапуска VS Code.

Демонстрация проблемы: https://i.stack.imgur.com/slQGP.jpg

Comment: А окружение в студии правильное выбрано, с этими библиотеками?

Comment: @CrazyElf я в принципе не работал с другим окружением с vs code, поэтому даже не знаю где оно настраивается. Возможно, конечно, случайно где-то сбилась настройка. Подскажите, где выбрать окружение?

Comment: Просмотрите информационную строку внизу, там, где кодировка и прочее, там ещё и питон с версией должен быть указан, это и есть окружение. Может там какой-то другой питон у вас выбран. Может быть несколько окружений с одной версией питона, всё не так просто.

Comment: @CrazyElf нет, python выбран основной и никаких других там нет

Comment: Тогда не знаю, значит проблема в чём-то другом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Временным решением проблемы стал откат `Pylance` до версии `2023.3.20`

Подробнее: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4162